# Prove that a vertex with minimum degree necessarily a vertex cut

Tags: graph-theory, neighbourhood

From *Graphs and Digraphs (7 ed.)*, proof of Theorem 4.6:

> If $G$ is not complete, then take a vertex $v$ with $\deg{v} = \delta(G)$ and note that $N(v)$ is a vertex-cut of $G$.

This is stated without proof, and I haven't been able to find any theorems about this in the book nor online. Why is it that a the neighborhood of a vertex of minimum degree is necessarily a vertex cut of its parent graph?

Comment: It is not specific to minimum degree vertices. If you remove all the neighbors of a vertex and if this vertex is not connected to every other vertices, then this vertex is disconnected from the rest of the graph. You easily verify that if $G$ is not complete and the vertex has minimum degree, then it can't be connected to every other vertices.

Comment: Any vertex in a connected graph whose degree is *less than the maximum* must have at least one other vertex that is not a neighbor. If you remove all neighbors of one of these, then that vertex and the other vertex are no longer connected. Thus the set of neighbors was a vertex cut.